# How can i make System.in read from a JTextField

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jtextfield

I am trying to make System.in InputStream read from a JTextField.

What i need it to do, is to allow `.read()` to proceed once a user presses enter in a JTextField with a String in it.

The issue is that I don't know when .read() will be invoked, and i want it to block without freezing the main thread, until enter is pressed by the user in the JTextField where it will notify the thread waiting.

So far i tried the following:

```
public class InputStreamHandlerThread extends Thread {

    private JTextField txt;
    public InputStreamHandlerThread(JTextField txt) {
        this.txt = txt;
        start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.setIn(new FakeInputStream());
    }

    class FakeInputStream extends InputStream {
        private int indx = 0;

        @Override
        public int read() throws IOException {
            if (indx == txt.getText().length()) {
                indx = 0;
                try {
                    synchronized (this) {
                        wait();
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            int byt = txt.getText().getBytes()[indx];
            indx++;
            return byt;

        }
    }
}
```

which is initialized and started by the GUI thread. 
So once the GUI loads, it creates an instance of this class and keeps a pointer so that when the enter key is pressed on the keyboard within the JTextField, it is notified to read from it.

```
       in = new JTextField();
       in.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent a) {
                if (a.getKeyChar() == '\n') {
                    inputStreamHandler.notify();
                }
            }
        });
```

So currently there are three threads:
 1. The main thread on what the GUI runs on
 2. The InputStream handler thread (See above ^)
 3. The thread that reads from System.in

The problem is that once i invoke `inputStreamHandler.notify();` it throws a `java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException` which according to the docs, is thrown if the thread is not the holder of the lock. 
How do i resolve this?

Thank you :-)

Comment: Use an ActionListener, when it's triggered, add the text to a BlockingQueue fro with which your FakeInputStream can read from

Comment: Also remember, Swing is not thread safe, so it's uncertain as to what your thread would actually read

Comment: @tobias_k  it's a text field not a text area :) MadProgrammer I'll look into that soon, thanks!!!

Comment: Allow me to ask you why you want `System.in` to read from a `JTextField`. Also, do you want the stream to read every key typed or only when the user presses Enter?

Comment: @user1803551 I am making a program allowing you to load any java program designed to run in command line, to a customizable gui. So i need to override the PrintStreams (done) and the Input stream (done after MadProgrammer's solution) As i said in my main post, i want to stream the bytes once Enter is pressed, thats why i have the condition in the key even afterall. It is now sorted woohoo! Ill post the solution as an answert for those still intrested :- )

Answer (score 0):

```
String text;

...

in.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        text = in.getText();
    }
});
```

Make sure you make text and in both fields.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but that was not what i was looking for... 
As i said,
_"I am trying to make System.in InputStream read from a JTextField."_
I know how to retreive the text from a JTextComponent but i didn't know how to feed that and create a class behaving like an InputStream to read from.